# Rest Url best practice for GET

Tags: api, rest, url

I need to build a restful url for getting an object back, and it is a little different than a typical /objectService/objectId.

Consider I have a  "Fruit Service", My service can do a GET on three different tables, an Apple table, a Banana table, and an Orange table.   All the gets return a Fruit object.

Is this an acceptable restful pattern ?

```
/fruitService/apple/123
/fruitService/orange/456
```

the service is not returning apple or orange objects, it is returning "fruit" objects, so I was not sure if it was ok to have apple/123 when 123 is an id of a fruit, not an apple object.

I thought this would be preferable over

```
/fruitservice/123?type=apple
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance,
Kim

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Ruby on Rails (which is not much)

> /fruitService/orange/456

should return the Orange object from the oranges table with id=456.
This is pretty much the best practice in rails.
In my opinion it reads better and seems more logical. If you are running a query against a fruit on the other hand, this would be a suitable url.

> /fruitService/fruit/456

This removes a lot of ambiguity from your api.

Answer (score 0):

Personally it would create a `Fruits` table that will have and ID and reference to apple, orange, and banana tables/entities/whatever. What's important is that IDs from `Fruits` table will be exposed to the consumers hence on simple and elegant endpoint can be used:

```
/fruits/{FID}/
```

to get a particular fruit. This way you avoid exposing the details and the model to the consumers.

**EDIT**

If you don't have access to DB hence the structure can't be changed I'd go for the following endpoints:

```
/fruits/orange/{ID}/
```

and so on. This is quite common practice in REST to use such endpoints - I mean with common root (*fruits*) not followed by *ID* but by other descriptor (*oranges*). E.g. `/food/categories/` or `/food/products/`.

Using the mentioned endpoint clearly states what are the available types and makes easier for the users to get what they need more quickly.

The drawback of this solution is that it violates open-closed principle. With every new table, new endpoint needs to be added.

To avoid adding new endpoints you can go with query params:

```
/fruits/{FID}/?view=orange
```

but you need to clearly specify what are available *view* options.

Comment: This is what I would love to do, however unfortunately I have no control over the database structure, I just have to access it.

Comment: What are the formats of returned fruits? All the same?

Comment: Yes, the same object is returned, I just need a way to communicate via the request which table to go get the item from.  I had read that you should only put parameters on search URLs , so did not want to do /fruits/id?type=apple